# improve as a intransitive verb

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to know if the sentence "We improve in a dark time" is grammatically correct and has a similar meaning with "We grow in a dark time(meaning we grow when we go through pain or difficulties)". As far as I know, when the verb 'improve' is used with a human subject, it is a transitive verb. When the verb is used as a transitive verb, it can have a human subject. So, is the sentence "We improve in a dark time" correct and does it mean "We grow in a dark time"?

Comment: both sentences have a similar meaning, but are not grammatically correct, they should be  "We improve in dark times" and "We grow in dark times" respectively. certainly your use of improve is correct

Answer (score 1):

"Improve" can be either transitive *or* intransitive, for example:

- I will improve.
- I will improve my grades.

When used intransitively, there will almost certainly be some kind of metric understood to be the thing you are improving upon.

Your specific example isn't quite right, but only because your use of "a dark time" is not correct. It should be:

> We improve *in dark times*.

Because you are making a generalisation, "we improve", it needs to apply to *any* 'dark time', not just *a* particular one. Of course, if you were speaking about a particular time retrospectively, you could perhaps say "we *improved* in a dark time", although I'd find "*during* a dark time" to be more idiomatic.